# Posicionamiento jquery nice-select

Tags: css

escribo para pedir consejo sobre mi siguiente problema:
Tengo un popup con varios select mediante el plugin nice-select, lo cual se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces si abro los dos primeros select, sus contenidos se ven por sobre el resto de los selects (lo que es lo correcto), pero al abrir el tercer select ("Detalle), su contenido se ve por detrás del cuarto select, es decir no se sobrepone como lo hacen los anteriores (y que es como debería ser) y se ve de sta manera: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente :

```
<div id="popup" class="popup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="content-popup">
      <div class="close"><a href="#" id="close"><img src="../../img/close.png"/></a></div>
      <div>
        <h4>Selección de Proyectos Asignados</h4>           
        <div class ="padre">
          <p style="margin-top: -1em;"><select id="proy-select" class="small"> <option value='0' data-display="Proyecto" >-- Sel Proyecto --</option> </select> <span id="msg1" style="color:#FF0000;display: none;">Debe ingresar al menos un Proyecto</span>
            <spam id="nproy" style="margin-top: 0.6em;margin-left: 0.2em;position: fixed;font-size: 0.8em;"></spam>
          </p>

          <p style="margin-top: 1.5em;margin-left: -5.8em"><select id="os-select" class="small"> <option value='0' data-display="Os" >-- Sel Os --</option> </select> <span id="nos" style="margin-top: 0.6em;margin-left: 0.3em;position: fixed;font-size: 0.8em"></span> </p>

          <p style="margin-top: 4em;margin-left: 0em;position: fixed"><select id="det-select" class="small"><option value='0' data-display="Detalle" >-- Sel Detalle --</option></select></p>
          <p style="margin-top: 6.5em;margin-left: 0em;position: fixed"><select id="ddsc-select" class="small"><option value='0' data-display="Descipción" >-- Sel Descripción --</option></select></p>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Para la Div contendor de los select (clase Padre), tengo lo siguiente en CSS:

```
.padre {display: flex;justify-content: left;align-items: left;}
```

Y por ultimo tengo esto en css para manejar el scrolling:

```
.nice-select.open .list { max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, la verdad el css para mi es un quebradero de cabeza..

Comment: No sé si el fallo será por eso pero estás cerrando un `select`dos veces. Y también usas la etiqueta `<spam>` que no existe, es `<span>`

Comment: Si gracias Blonfu, lo que me dices ya se corrigió, pero el problema se mantiene